# Swapping two dimensional array using python

Tags: python, arrays

I need help in swapping 2 elements using Python for the following type of list that is generated randomly:

**Actual list**

```
list = [('a0', 'b5'), ('a0', 'b6'), ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a1', 'b3'), ('a1', 'b5'), ('a1', 'b6'), ('a2', 'b0'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b5'), ('a3', 'b4')]
```

**After swapping element `'a1'` with `'a2'`**

```
Array [('a0', 'b5'), ('a0', 'b6'), ('a2', 'b0'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b5'), ('a3', 'b4'), ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a1', 'b3'), ('a1', 'b5'), ('a1', 'b6')]
```

This is my code:

```
r1 = random.randrange(1, 5, 1)
r2 = random.randrange(4, 9, 2)
a = ['a' + str(j) for j in range(r1)]
b = ['b' + str(j) for j in range(r2)] 

dd = []
total = math.floor((r1 * r2) * 80 / 100)
print("80% connection", total)

for x in a:
    for y in b:
        r3 = random.randrange(1, total, 2)
        if (r3 < 10):
            dd.append((x, y))
print("Connection", dd)

cop = [eb[0] for eb in dd]

s1 = random.randrange(len(a))
s2 = random.randrange(len(a))

print("Number to Swap", s1)
print("Range Number Two", s2)

for swp in range(len(dd)):
    if swp ==s1:
        for tes in range(len(a)):
            if a[s1] == cop[swp]:
                temp = dd[s1]
                dd[s1] = dd[s2]
                dd[s2] = temp
            else:
                for tes in range(len(a)):
                    if a[s2] == cop[swp]:
                        temp = dd[s1+1]
                        dd[s1+1] = dd[swp]
                        dd[swp] = temp

print("New Swap Array", dd)
```

Comment: Show your code and attempts please. [ask]

Comment: @JulienBernu code is added please review again

Comment: I'm not understanding the example.  Why does "('a1', 'b3')" go to "('a2', 'b5')"? Could you simplify it?

Comment: @RobertPrévost, because the question states "Swapping element a1 with a2", meaning for each tuple in the list, swap elements beginning that begin with `'a1'` to the position of elements that begin with `'a2'`

Comment: As I see it the target output is inconsistent with the question statement.

Answer (score 0):

This works with lists similar to your example, swaps elements only when the actual list contains tuples with `'a1'` or `'a2'` as the first element, could easily be modified to work with other and more elements.

```
new_dd = []
first_els = []
second_els = []
end_els = []

for i in dd:
    if int(i[0][1]) < 1:
        new_dd.append(i)
    elif int(i[0][1]) > 2:
        end_els.append(i)
    elif int(i[0][1]) == 1:
        first_els.append(i)
    elif int(i[0][1]) == 2:
        second_els.append(i)

new_dd.extend(second_els)
new_dd.extend(first_els)
new_dd.extend(end_els)

print(dd)
print(new_dd)
```

Output:

```
[('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'b2'), ('a0', 'b3'), ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a1', 'b3'), ('a2', 'b0'), ('a2', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b3'), ('a3', 'b0'), ('a3', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3')]
[('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'b2'), ('a0', 'b3'), ('a2', 'b0'), ('a2', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b3'), ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a1', 'b3'), ('a3', 'b0'), ('a3', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3')]
```